# PHP Mysqli - SELECT * or SELECT COUNT(*) when result is 0?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Is there any difference in performance between `SELECT *` and `SELECT COUNT(*)` when no rows will be found?

My chat script check every second for new messages so it would be good to know if I need count(*)

What would be faster and better for the server:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "blablabla");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

}
```

OR

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "blablabla");
 $menge = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 $menge = $menge[0];

if($menge > 0)
{

}
```

When no rows will be found?! I'm asking that for AJAX chat and most of the time there will be no new rows.

Comment: when you have no rows, `SELECT *` will return nothing, `SELECT COUNT(*)` will *count* that and return 0. you could have checked that yourself by simply running the queries against your database

Comment: If you do a count and the result is not 0 then you will probably need to do another select to get the rows anyway.

Comment: `SELECT *` puts whole row to result, but `SELECT COUNT(*)` only increase counter on each matching. So if you need to get count use `SELECT COUNT(*)`, you will save as memory as time

Comment: @Kickstart may be that's why I asked this question?!

Comment: @AnneSchwarz well, you'd also notice any performance differences between the queries if you **run them**. also: any difference when there are no rows are neglectably small, especially compared to a second. you are optimizing at the entirely wrong spot here. you should rather worry about the case when there *are* rows, which will happen (or you wouldn't have to check), and in which case it's *obvious* that retreiving just a number is faster than retreiving all data.

Comment: @AnneSchwarz - With a basic query the time difference would be negligable between the 2 (well within natural variation). With a complex query there could be a significant difference as likely with just a COUNT you could simplify the query (for example if the full query needs a sub query to get the latest details for a grouped set, while the count might only be interested in whether there is a row).

Comment: So if the query would be just "if id > 7" then it wouldn't make any real difference when it's done every second (ajax chat)? Or would it make any significant difference when there are like 1 million rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a basic query the time difference would be negligible between the 2 (well within natural variation when executing a query repeatedly). With a complex query there could be a significant difference as likely with just a COUNT you could use a simplified query.

For example if the full query needs a sub query to get the latest details for a grouped set then this could make the full query quite slow. However the count might only be interested in whether there is a row (rather than the details of the latest row) and so not require the sub query. This could make a major difference.

Assuming you had an index on the id and the value you are using is at or close to the max value (ie, you are not expecting to return the full 1m records, rather a couple max from the last few seconds) then I wouldn't expect a significant difference caused by the amount of data returned.

The big constant performance hits are making the connection to MySQL, and the basic processing of a query by the database (ie, processing the request. not performing the query). These provide a fairly constant overhead for any query, and quite a significant one for a simple query which is fast once it is executed. Because of this the overhead from performing 2 queries sometimes (when new rows have been added) is likely to dwarf the negligible saving from just getting a count unless there are new records.